# Can I use binding.js for databinding on a web project?

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-binding, windows-8

Windows 8 SDK comes with very cool data binding JavaScript samples.

More info here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465051(v=VS.85).aspx#Extend_Your_First_Metro_Style_App_JavaScript_Using_Templates_and_Binding

From what I understand, you can define data binding and data template quite easily.

However, I am not sure I am allowed to use binding.js in my project (supported for Windows apps only, doesn't work on firefox or chrome)

Is there an equivalent for the web (e.g. jQuery extension)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your closest equivalent might be data templating.

You can perhaps give this a try and see if it suits your needs:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/05/07/jquery-templates-and-data-linking-and-microsoft-contributing-to-jquery.aspx